# Get attribute of current controller action in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wish to display the current action of the controller on my MVC View in a human readable format.

I understand you can acquire the name of the current action through:
`@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action")`
this returns e.g. 'Index' in the example below

What I am looking to do is something like:

```
[DisplayName=Resources.Overview]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

and then print that DisplayName on the page, some pseudo-code like:

`@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").GetAttribute("DisplayName")`
which would return 'Overview' from Resources

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first  make a reflection to the method with **Type.GetMethodInfo**

```
string actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(actionName);
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false);
if (attribute.Length > 0)
   actionName = ((DisplayNameAttribute)attribute[0]).DisplayName;
else 
   actionName = type.Name;   // fallback to the type name of the controller
```

And then you can pass the actionName to the View using something like

```
   ViewBag.name = actionName;
```

and then get the Viewbag variable from the view

Comment: This seems exactly like what I need. One further question: Is it possible to use this dynamically inside the View itself? I can hardcore e.g. `Type type = Type.GetType(HomeController);` but is it possible to get the current controller's type? `Type type = Type.GetType(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]);` does not seem to work. If I can get that line working I'd be set

Comment: I'd recommend creating a custom action filter where you'd put this code. You can make it global by adding it in `FilterConfig.cs` and then, assuming you've added the `DisplayName` attribute, that `ViewBag` member will be set to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your proposition. I believe I'm going to use the above code in a shared layout and use `@ViewContext.Controller.GetType()` to get the type of the current controller

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the DisplayName inside the Viewbag and retrieve it in code, for every page that requires it?

For Example,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Viewbag.DisplayName = 'Resources.Overview'
    return View();
}
```

then in any view that populates the DisplayName value, you can display it at the top with the following,

```
<head>
    @ViewBag.DisplayName
</head>
```

Comment: I have started to realise you actually want the action name specifically, so my method though it may work, wouldn't be without mess... i will leave it here, but you can disregard it if you dont like it :P

Comment: I've considered that, but I also want to do the same for my controller having a DisplayName and show both (and potentially even other data too which I could set on controller-level).  Which would result in me having to copypaste the line e.g. `ViewBag.ControllerDisplayName = Resources.Home` on every single method. This inefficiency made me curious if there is a solution along the lines I'm thinking of.

Comment: Agreed, the implementation is easy, but its just messy!