# How to check Whether method have AllowAnonymous attribute or not in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have Controller in which Some method have authorize attribute and some method have AllowAnonymous
So, I want to check at the time of calling method are Authorize or AllowAnonymous

This is my controller with method name login

```
[AllowAnonymouse]

Public ActionResult Login(){}
```

So in different class i want to check whether this method is Authorize or AllowAnonymous

Comment: Use reflection, `typeof(YourController).GetMethod("Login").GetCustomAttributes()`

Answer (score 1):

```
string actionName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(actionName);
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false);
if (attribute.Length > 0)
   actionName = ((DisplayNameAttribute)attribute[0]).DisplayName;
else 
   actionName = type.Name;
```

check this link:

[Get attribute of current controller action in MVC View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740411/get-attribute-of-current-controller-action-in-mvc-view)